# Calling a C# method from a Typescript method in Angular 7

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, angular7

I got an Angular project which defines the UI and it's events etc.

I also got a C# project which does some business logic.

The C# side is preparing results, and I need to somehow read them in a page's click events and display them.

I can either reference the C# project in the Angular's project, but since I control both the Angular and the C# code, I can also just add the C# files directly to Angular project without the need to reference an outside project.

Pseudo code of what I need:

C# code can be like:

```
public List<Agent> CSharpGetAgents()
{
   .. fetch data from db
   .. call web service
   .. prepare list of agents
   return agentsList;
}
```

And on the Typescript side I want to do something Like:

```
let agents : Agent[] = CSharpGetAgents();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: C# is server side* and Angular is client side, the only way for Angular to call C# is via a webservice. (* Yes, Blazor will be a thing one day, but for this purpose, it's not)

Comment: Isn't there a way to convert a .NET type to a TS type by some marshaling or what not?

Comment: No, the two things are completely unrelated.

Comment: This is pretty much the point of a web service API.

Comment: If it's about the types, I can always use json instead of returning the object itself. Or is it just not possible to make a C# call in TS at all, no matter what I reference?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make a C# call in TypeScript.

C# runs on the server in the form of a compiled DLL. TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, which runs on the client.

To communicate between these, you would need to build an API with service endpoints on the server. Then you would need to retrieve the data by requesting it from the client.